# How do I know when a UIWebView has exited full screen?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

for an iOS app I have a Youtube video which is loaded in using the following HTML/objc

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed allowScriptAccess=\"always\" id=\"yt\" src=\"%@&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=yt\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"262\" height=\"187\"></embed>\
</body></html>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Which loads up and plays fine. The issue I'm having is that my app is strictly portrait view and you cannot rotate it while in the app. If you're watching the youtube video the webview does an override (or something like that) that allows the user to rotate for full screen which is fine however if they close / select "Done" on the video and it closes while in landscape the app is all of a sudden in landscape and is severely cut off. How do I prevent this from happening while still allowing landscape playback of video?

Comment: did you override the viewControllers `shouldAutorotate` to return NO?

Comment: @katzenhut that's the trick, I want them to be able to autorotate during the video but the app needs to go back to portrait once they reduce the webview from fullscreen back to it's normal size.

Comment: you might need to subclass uiwebview then. make it take a delegate in its contructor, and then call back to that delegate when it finishes. read up on delegation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings (App Target > General > Deployment Info > Device Orientation), select Portrait, Landscape Left and Landscape Right.

In your root view controller, add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

If everything gets loaded into this view controller, that should be all you have to do. If you find that some views are rotating when they shouldn't, add this same code to their view controllers.

The controller for the fullscreen video will use the supported orientations specified in the target settings, and so will allow rotation to landscape. When you close the video, the view will rotate back to portrait.